# How to make Zapier code step fail while getting output info

Tags: javascript, zapier

My task history shows a lot of successful code steps that actually were not successful. How do I write my JavaScript code to make the task fail (so that I'm alerted there is something wrong) AND receive an output? So far, I've only been able to do one or the other - When I make the task fail (by throwing an exception or calling `callback('Failure', output)`, no output is visible in the task history. `console.log` results in an empty log, for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nobody seems to know the answer and one person thinks it's a bad question. At this point I'm fairly certain that what I was asking for is not possible. So, in case anyone wonders, I came to the conclusion that you should:

- Include any useful information in the exception you're throwing, or
- Catch all possible exceptions and add another code step which throws an exception based on the output of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I asked Zapier support this same question, and they couldn't help me. The only thing I can think to do is to output the results of the code step and then use the Zapier filter to continue if output["result"] = "code ran okay" (for example). Currently exploring serverless functions as an alternative to a Zapier code step.